# Cannot connect with OpenSSH from certain networks

Tags: ssh

I used to connect to connect to my server using OpenSSH using this command:

```
ssh root@my-server.com
```

but now I've changed my location, and I can no longer connect, here is the debug report when I use the `-v` parameter with the `ssh` command:

```
ssh root@my-server.com -v

OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/riless/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my-server.com [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/riless/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

and after a while, it outputs me this:

```
Connection closed by xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Notes: PuTTY works normally, but not OpenSSH; I'm on Ubuntu

EDIT1:
content of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file (without the commented lines):

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

content of `/home/riless/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host xx.xxx.xxx.xx
User root
Port 22
Hostname xx.xxx.xxx.xx
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

EDIT2: whene I try to change Ciphers using this command line:

```
ssh root@70.32.72.141 -c aes256-ctr -v
```

it prompt me for password, but the console freezes just after that:

```
root@xx.xx.xx.xxx's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xx.xxx ([xx.xx.xx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: Contents for `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/home/riless/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added a line in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` referring to many forums.

```
Ciphers arcfour
```

Now, I can connect to the server, **but there is still some issues**: 
The console freezes when I run somme commands like `vim`, `htop`

**UPDATE**:
I've found a solution for this, but don't know how does this works.

Just set the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) on your ethernet or wireless interface to something really small.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1100  # (or eth0 for ethernet)
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a limitation in place for the source connection of the root user in your /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Specifically, your `authorized_keys` probably looks like this:

```
from="trusted.host.some.domain.ext,10.0.0.*,:*.untrusted.network.ext" ssh-rsa [your key] root@localhost
```

If you connection doesn't macth the "from" pattern of if it's explicitly excluded from that pattern, the connection will be denied.

Comment: It Works with PuTTY, It's not a limitation of place.